# Revit material physical asset parameters

Tags: parameters, extract, revit-api, revitpythonshell

I'm trying to extract parameters from Revit materials' physical asset (where applicable and set).
Could someone explain it to me why I can see some parameters given in the Material Browser and yet I can't get these values returned with Python Revit Shell? (see attached picture)
Oddly, the Revit Lookup doesn't show the set values either.

[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h5wK.png)

Thanks!